# How to I configure sox to work on mp4?

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, sox

I am using ubuntu 8.10. I wanted to know what I need to do to get SOX to work on MP4 files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes..sox has support for mp4, m4p, & m4a. They're marked as optional in the pdf manual. Perhaps one has to compile sox from the source files e.g. the sox(version number).tar.gz source package...unpack it using an archive manager, then do something like make, make install, etc... while including the additional option for the mp4 types of files. Checkout the README file in the package to make sure.

Comment: Any more info? I think I read that you need to install LAME to get it to work....

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure there's any support in SOX for them? You may have to use a separate encoder/decoder to go to/from mp4.